# Dijkstra boost distance map gives random values

Tags: boost, distance, dijkstra

I am trying to solve the problem where I am given:

1. **a graph** with **v vertices** and **e edges** and the **edge weights**.

**Output:**

1. the weight of the minimum spanning tree
2. the distance between the first node(0) and the farthest node(which can be any node except 0)

**Problem:**

My distance map just stores a random unknown number.

**My input is:**

```
5
5 6
0 1 1
0 2 2 
1 2 5
1 3 1
3 2 2
2 4 3
4 5
1 0 91
2 0 50
2 1 849
3 0 451
3 1 724
8 25
1 0 91
2 0 176
2 1 658
3 0 61
3 1 740
4 0 21
4 1 817
4 2 407
4 3 469
5 0 468
5 1 493
5 2 400
5 3 814
5 4 86
6 0 611
6 1 457
6 2 776
6 4 452
6 5 4
7 0 601
7 2 722
7 3 11
7 4 249
7 5 530
7 6 632
9 9
1 0 64
3 1 914
4 1 331
4 2 824
5 3 509
7 5 520
7 6 460
8 1 415
8 7 263
3 2
1 0 533
2 1 920
```

The first number is the number of testcases,then for each testcase I have the number of vertices and edges,followed by the vertice number(2 of the denoting an edge) and the respective weights.

**Example:**

```
testcases

no_vert no_edges

node_1 node_2 weight_1
node_2 node_3 weight_2
ect....
```

**Output: is the weight of spanning tree and the distance between first and farthest node:**

```
7 5
592 451
450 176
3386 1262
1453 1453
```

So instead of this correct output I get:

```
7 5
592 2147483647
450 2147483647
3386 2147483647
```

Which means there is a problem with my dijkstras approach. I am not where there is a mistake,I assume it is with the distance vector,but where?

Here is my **code**

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : boost_ex_1.cpp
// Author      : priya
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>

#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property,property<edge_weight_t, int> > Graph;

    //vertex and edge descriptor
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;


int testcases();

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n=0;
    cin>>n;
    while(n--)
    {
        testcases();
    }

    return 0;
}


int testcases()
{
    //creation of graphs


    //get number of edges and vertices

    int NEDGES,NVERT;
    cin>>NVERT>>NEDGES;

    //graph g

    Graph g(NVERT);
    Vertex SOURCE=0;
    int a,b,c;

    //property map for edge weights
    property_map<Graph,edge_weight_t>::type weightMap = get(edge_weight,g);

    //fill graph details in g

    for(int i=0;i<NEDGES;++i)
    {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        bool success;
        Edge e;
        tie(e,success) = add_edge(a,b,g);
        weightMap[e]=c;
    }

//filled graph with edges and vertices and weight in weightMap

    vector<Edge> spanning_tree;
    kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g,back_inserter(spanning_tree));

    a=0;

    for(vector<Edge>::iterator ei=spanning_tree.begin();ei!=spanning_tree.end();++ei)
    {
        a+=weightMap[*ei];
    }


    vector<int>distancep(NVERT); //distance ebtween nodes

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g,SOURCE,distance_map(&distancep[0]));
    b=0;

    for(int i=0;i<num_vertices(g);++i)
    {

      b=max(b,distancep[i]);
    }


    cout << a <<" "<< b << endl;




    return 0;

    }
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Thank you.

**EDIT::** *In addition as you can see in my output,the last output is missing,Im also not able to figure out why.Thank you*

Answer (score 2):

*I wanted to post the answer,In case someone has the same problem.*

**So,** the first problem was the while loop it should be

```
while(n--)
```

**NOT**

```
while(--n)
```

It misses a testcase of the input.

Secondly, I had declared the grah as `directedS`, which is wrong,it should be `undirectedS`,and **gave random distance values,since the values for distance was empty the otherway around.**